Parse Json Langchain stream result to text
i have a streamlit app with langchain and im using a ConversationChain.
Since i want to  stream the result to a chat, i only want to get the "response" field from the output, e.g.
{
  "input": "hallo",
  "history": "",
  "response": "Hello there!" <---- response i want to get back for streaming
}

Im only using the StrOutputParser, but this just results in printing out the whole json.


from openai import OpenAI
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import streamlit as st
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser

from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder, PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains.llm import LLMChain
from langchain.schema import (
    SystemMessage,
    HumanMessage,
    AIMessage
)

from langchain.chains.conversation.base import ConversationChain
from langchain.chains.conversation.memory import ConversationStringBufferMemory


llm: ChatOpenAI = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", api_key=api_key, streaming=True, callbacks=[StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()]))

conversation_Chain: ConversationChain = ConversationChain(
    llm=llm,
    memory=ConversationStringBufferMemory()
)

chain = conversation_buf | StrOutputParser()

st.write_stream(chain.stream("Hallo"))

Is it possible to parse streaming result with a specific outputparser, which maybe parses for the field response?
I tried multiple outputparsers

to stream the final output you can use a RunnableGenerator:

from openai import OpenAI
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import streamlit as st
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser

from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder, PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains.llm import LLMChain
from langchain.schema import (
    SystemMessage,
    HumanMessage,
    AIMessage
)

from langchain.chains.conversation.base import ConversationChain
from langchain.chains.conversation.memory import ConversationStringBufferMemory
from langchain.schema.runnable import RunnableGenerator

llm: ChatOpenAI = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", api_key=api_key, streaming=True, callbacks=[StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()]))

def _transform(input_stream):
    for chunk in input_stream:
        yield chunk['response']

conversation_Chain: ConversationChain = ConversationChain(
    llm=llm,
    memory=ConversationStringBufferMemory()
)  

chain = conversation_buf | RunnableGenerator(_transform)

st.write_stream(chain.stream("Hallo, write a 15 lines text"))

see reference at: https://github.com/langchain-ai/langserve/discussions/308

Had the same problem. It returned a lot of JSON in my streamlit app.
I solved the problem using something this example:
retrieval_chain = (
    {
        "context": vector_store.as_retriever().with_config(run_name="Docs"),
        "question": RunnablePassthrough(),
    }
    | prompt
    | llm
    | StrOutputParser()
)

raw_response = st.empty()
reply = raw_response.write_stream(retrieval_chain.stream("hello there"))

Source:
https://python.langchain.com/docs/expression_language/streaming/#non-streaming-components
